# Netbeans 7.0.1 Cannot insert image on the SWING component with visual editor

Tags: swing, netbeans-7

I'm trying to insert some images in the jLabel on SWING. I'm using Netbeans 7.0.1 and using the visual drag and drop tool. When trying to insert image, I got some troubles. I read the tutorial on [netbeans.org](http://netbeans.org/kb/docs/java/gui-image-display.html) but jLabel > icon property doesn't match with my 7.0.1.
Do you have same problems as I faced? Please help on this problem. 
[I could not post image for my low reputation]

Comment: Can you be more specific about what is your problem?  1) Are you able to add JPG, PNG type of images but not able to load some other extension?  2) Are you facing a problem with a step given in the tutorial? I am able to add an image to the Label in NetBeans IDE 7.0.1 hence need specific information about your problem so that I can help you here.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I resolved that problem:

```
ImageIcon img = new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/com/yourPackage/resources/img.jpg"));
myLabel.setIcon(img);
```

It worked fine whit static images as well as GIF's..
Hope this helps!